# UICollectionView datasource not working as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

So I've ran into a unique problem. I have a UICollectionView that works find, as long as there's at least 2 objects in the array I'm pulling from.

```
- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Allocating space for %i photos in collectionView", [CCPhotos sharedPhotos].photos.count);
    return [CCPhotos sharedPhotos].photos.count;
}

// configure cells
- (UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"PhotoCell" forIndexPath: indexPath];

    NSLog(@"Creating cell for row %i", indexPath.row);

    for (UIView* view in cell.contentView.subviews)
        [view removeFromSuperview];

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0f;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    // Add image to cell
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [[CCPhotos sharedPhotos].photos objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];

    // size imageView and set content mode
    imageView.frame = cell.contentView.frame;

    // add imageView to cell
    [cell.contentView addSubview: imageView];


    return cell;
}
```

`numberOfItemsInSection` always gets called and returns the correct value, but if it's less then 2, `cellForItemAtIndexPath` does not get called. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention I used my own flow layout that sets it up as such:

```
 - (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(ITEM_WIDTH, ITEM_HEIGHT);
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
        self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, (320 - ITEM_WIDTH) / 2, 0, 0);
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 320 - ITEM_WIDTH;


    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: So to phrase your question differently, when there is supposed to be one cell displayed, none are?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, but substituted a local mutable array in place of [CCPhotos sharedPhotos].photos -- it worked fine with one photo. Does the log you have in numberOfItemsInSection return 1 when you have one photo? If so, if you log that one photo, does it give you what you expect?

Comment: I figured out the problem. I'm not sure if it's because of I implemented a zooming effect when panning to a photo, but my `itemSize` was too large. I set `ITEM_WIDTH` and `ITEM_HEIGHT` to smaller values and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I'm not sure if it's because of I implemented a zooming effect when panning to a photo, but my itemSize was too large. I set ITEM_WIDTH and ITEM_HEIGHT to smaller values and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the item is off-screen, in which case `numberOfItemsInSection` would return 1 but `cellForItemAtIndexPath` would not be called. Check your layout.

You can override `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` like this to verify what attributes, if any, are being returned.

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    NSLog(@"%@", attributes);
    return attributes;
}
```

If none are returned, then it's something about the specifics of your layout (or a flow layout bug) causing the item to appear off-screen.

Answer (score 0):

First,i'm sorry,my english is very poor!

Did you write the collection's layout,dataSource and delegate?

eg.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(91.0f, (screenSize.height - TopNavigationBarHeight - 24.0f) / 3.0f);
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 11.0f);
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0f;
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0f;
self.stepCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, TopNavigationBarHeight, screenSize.width, screenSize.height - TopNavigationBarHeight) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
self.stepCollectionView.dataSource = self;
self.stepCollectionView.delegate = self;
[self.stepCollectionView registerClass:[StepThumbnailCollectionViewCell class]
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier:ItemIdentifier];
[self.view addSubview:self.stepCollectionView];
```

I hope it helps.